# In AND gate how two bits turns into 1 bit?

Tags: cpu, bit

In Book, "But how do it know" I am trying to understand how CPU actually works. I got the concept of bit. But I am not getting this line: "The computer part has a device that does something with bits. If you have 2 bits and you connect those two bits to input, the device looks at those bits and "Decides" Whether to turn one output bit on or off"

Author explains a little later, " when both inputs are off, the output is on, so.... how do you get electricity at the output if both inputs are off?. Well, that is an excellent question, and the excellent answer is that every one of these devices is also connected to power."

HOW?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://eletronics.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you are talking about is an XNOR gate. These gates are similar to AND gates but also activate when both inputs are 0.

Logic gates use power similar to how many other electrical devices do. For example, a light switch only turns on the lightbulb when you apply the correct input (closing the switch). The gates simply have a more complicated switch that activates when the correct inputs "close the switch" and allow current to flow from the power source to the output of the gate.

The internals of logic gates can get fairly complicated which is why we simplify the logic to easily identifiable boolean logic gate symbols and their corresponding truth tables. You'll notice that these symbols often don't include any power inputs as they are assumed and omitted from the boolean logic diagrams.

[image: XNOR]

https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/digital-logic-gates/xnor-gate/